# Visual Composer slider images with text

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer

I need to make a slider with images and title on every image for wordpress page. Pages are built using visual composer. Curretnly, I know I can use image carousel, but With it I can not add title on images. 
Is there other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in using revolution slider. It creates shortcode which can be added in visual composer. Visual composer than creates a widget which can be added inside a row.